# Which settings affect error 413 - Request entity too large

Tags: php, apache, http

I'm uploading a 3.5MB file to the server, as `POST` over `HTTP`, and recieveing `413 - Request entity too large`. My PHP settings:

`upload_max_filesize` is `100MB`

`post_max_size` is `100MB`

What else could be causing this?

Comment: have you restarted your `Apache` server after the update of `php.ini` ?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code please?  If this is being submitted through a `<form>` did you make sure to include your `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: @Crackertastic, the code is working on other servers, so it's not code-related

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing **B** from **MB**

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
```